# How to pass data in url without Query in Retrofit

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, retrofit

I am using Retrofit for API calls.. My API is like this https://test/update/123456789..

In this API need to pass "123456789" as value.. Can anyone help me to do this using Retrofit.. How can I pass this value w/o Query..

Thanks in Advance..:)

```
fun updatePriceTesting(@Query("device_id") deviceId: String, @Query("appId") appId: String, @Body RequestBody: RequestBody) : Deferred
```

Response>

Comment: `@GET("/test/update/:id) fun whatever(@Path("id") id: Int)` -- see the "URL Manipulation" section in [the Retrofit docs](https://square.github.io/retrofit/).

Comment: @CommonsWare okay give me sometime i will try

Comment: It will be something like this 
`@GET("/yourUpdatePathThatWillBeAppendedToBaseUrl/{id})
 fun update(@Path("id") id: Int)` also your request type may be @POST or @PUT it depends on your Api implementation

Comment: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "589656966" got this exception

Comment: @CommonsWare java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URL  does not contain "{id}". (parameter #1)

Comment: Sorry, Mohammed had the correct syntax. `@GET("/test/update/{id}) fun whatever(@Path("id") id: Int)`

Comment: if you are passing a string change data type from `@Path("id") id: Int` to `@Path("id") id: String`

Comment: it throws error like this java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URL does not contain "{id}". (parameter #1)

Answer (score 2):

To pass a value in retrofit you have to annotate it as @Query,or @Path,in case you dont want to use @Query,you can use @Path in the method parameter ,for example : if you want to send a value to your api , let us say
[www.fb.com/post,to](http://www.fb.com/post,to) pass id of post to retrieve,we have to do it like that:

```
@Get("www.fb.com/post/{post_id}")
```

if your id is an int then you can use :

```
Call<Post> getPost( @Path("post_id") int postId);
```

but if it was an string :

```
Call<Post> getPost( @Path("post_id") String postId);
```

and then you can call this method :

```
yourApiServiceObj.getPost(thePostId);
```

Comment: Tried this but got error like this "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URL does not contain "{id}". (parameter #1)

Comment: in your requestBody or whatever your url was,just put {id} instead of 123456789

Comment: when i use id like this means it throws error java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URL does not contain "{id}". (parameter #1)

Answer (score 0):

As it's appears that this is not clear I will write it as answer

if your url will be like this `update/123456789?appId=5452266` which is `update/device_id?appId=5452266`  then your function call will be

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("update/{device_id}")
fun updatePriceTesting(@Path("device_id") deviceId: String, @Field("appId") appId: String, @Body RequestBody: RequestBody) : Deferred
```

if your url will be like this `update/5452266?device_id=123456789` which is `update/appId?device_id=123456789`  then your function call will be

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("update/{appId}")
fun updatePriceTesting(@Field("device_id") deviceId: String, @Path("appId") appId: String, @Body RequestBody: RequestBody) : Deferred
```

if your url will be like this `update/123456789/5452266` which is `update/device_id/appId`  then your function call will be

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("update/{device_id}/{appId}")
fun updatePriceTesting(@Path("device_id") deviceId: String, @Path("appId") appId: String, @Body RequestBody: RequestBody) : Deferred
```